# How can I improve this sticky footer code & fix one minor issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer, sticky-footer

For some reason you need to drag the window in jsfiddle to get it going, but it works fine onLoad in context.

The idea behind this is that if the content exceeds the height of the window, it will removeClass ".sticky" which is slamming the footer down absolute to the bottom of the page. Otherwise, it's a sticky footer.

It *should* be pretty elegant. My issue is that for a moment, the footer clips off the content. I want it to removeClass ".sticky" when the aqua background of the section[role="main"] meets the footer's purple background and not a pixel later. I can't seem to get this going.

The footer is always the same height... can I just subtract it from something?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('aside[role="sidebar"]').height($(window).height());

if( $('section[role="main"]').height() >= $(window).height() ) {
    $('.footer').removeClass('sticky');
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('aside[role="sidebar"]').height($(window).height());

    if( $('section[role="main"]').height() <= $(window).height() ) {
        $('.footer').addClass('sticky');
    }
    else {
        $('.footer').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
});
```

**Working example here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/LxvQ9/ make sure to resize to get it going initallly. Again, this is some issue with jsFiddle. Works fine on my site onLoad.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

While calculating `height` of any element, we also need to consider `padding` and `border` if any.

In jQuery we use `outerHeight` to get the height of any element including `padding` and `border`.

So, in your case, we are using only `height` and that's why some text is clipping.

Use the following code to properly calculate the `height` and update the footer class.

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function(){
    //When Window is Resized
    $(window).resize(makeFooterSticky);
    //Run once on page load
    mkaeFooterSticky();
});

function makeFooterSticky() {

    $('aside[role="sidebar"]').height($(window).height());

    if( $('section[role="main"]').outerHeight() <= $(window).height() - $('.footer').outerHeight() ) {
        $('.footer').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.footer').removeClass('sticky');
    }
}
```

Hope this should work.

Let me know if there are any issues.

JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hVzat/3/